# iMac goes offline from WIFI several times each hour

Tags: wireless-networking, safari, imac

Aargh! I have an iMac running Lion and have to manually get online several times each hour. I get a notification that I am not connected to the internet, i then run "diagnostics' it says my system configuration has changed and suddenly green lights and I am up and running- how on earth can i stay on the wifi more consistently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be a modem/router issue, I've had faulty routers before that drop out every 10 minutes and have to re-connect. You could try to connect to different wifi networks to test, to get a clearer picture of what is going on.

Try one or more of the following tests, If the iMac works as expected (no drop-outs) you will know if it is your modem/router.

- Try connecting to your phone's internet connection by setting up a wifi hotspot. The settings differ for each phone, [here](http://www.ausbt.com.au/turn-your-iphone-4-or-4s-or-new-3g-ipad-into-a-personal-wifi-hotspot) are instructions on how to set it up on an iPhone.
- Try a usb dongle. If you or a friend/ family member have a usb dongle you use for work or something, just borrow it.
- Take your iMac to someone else's house, and attempt to connect to their wifi
- Try using a spare/different router at home
- If you have nice neighbours and you can see their wifi connection from your house, ask them if you can try connecting temporarily.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Wi-Fi network is conflicting with a neighbour's network. You can view extended information about the channels you're using by holding down Option when you click on the Wi-Fi icon in the Menu Bar, then use this to choose a channel that is distant from your neighbours.

Some more detail here: [Wi-Fi problems on mac](http://www.leftcolumn.net/2013/04/01/fix-wi-fi-problems-on-mac-osx/) - particularly the last para which really seems to be a problem with extended AirPort networks (i.e.: multiple Wi-Fi devices).